# Perform a command in a different shell

Tags: shell, unix

Where I work, we have a command, let's call it `kuku`, that, when invoked, diverts me to a new shell. i.e., I get:

```
old_shell> kuku
kuku> exit
old_shell> ...
```

I need to run a certain script in the `kuku` shell, but I don't want to manually enter it and/or stay there. i.e., I would like to use something like `kuku; <do stuff>; exit;`. However, that won't work since once it enters `kuku`, it doesn't get to the other commands.

Is there any way to open a shell, feed it some commands, and exit automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends strongly on how `kuku` works. If `kuku` is more or less compatible with other shells, then `kuku -c "cmd1; cmd2"` should work.

Another option is to put the commands for `kuku` in a file `script.kuku`, then run that with `kuku < script.kuku`.

Finally, [`expect`](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm) or any of its clones can be used to automate virtually any command.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of `kuku` should tell you how to pass commands to the `kuku` shell for execution (e.g. using a script file, using standard input, try `man kuku`). If kuku does not provide such features, you might want to have a look at [Expect](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm).

Answer (score 0):

Say you had a shell script called mostlyharmless.sh that "does stuff", then in the example of ssh you would write `ssh user@server 'bash -s' < mostlyharmless.sh`. Answering your question would be easier if you were more specific about the shell. All of them work a bit different...